# For two different pages, facebook like button posts the same url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I place a facebook like button in two diffrent pages. 
Url of A page is: 
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=pages/page_a;

Url of B page is:
www.mysite.com/index.php?route=pages/page_b;

Liking any one of the two pages, facebook will only post the link of page A. AND the facebook like button shows the same like counts in each page(which is the like counts of page A).

i do not use the "webiste" as the og type tag value(which represent the whole site). I have tried the product, game and activity, but still the same problem.

I have try the facebook debug tool to clear the facebook cache. Still no luck.

I have spend two days, pulling my hair out and trying to figure out how to fix. But no luck.
Can anyone please tell me how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try setting the "href" attribute explicitly?

Comment: You are a life saver!!! Thank you so much! The problem has been fixed now :)

Comment: Damn, next time I'll make my comment an answer :D Glad it helped!